# Front-page.php url slug

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a very simple question. I'm building a very small and basic website where I have coded a simple menu. I want the current page from the menu to be highlighted in yellow.

In order to do that, I have added an if statement that looks for the **url slug** and it is true, to add the CSS class to that particular HTML element.

Works fine for 'service' and 'about-us' but what about the home page? What URL slug do I use for that? In addition my 'index' url slug is not working for whatever reason.

note: the class "modern" is CSS trigger to change the color.

```
 <ul class="list-inline">
            <!-- empty site_url() will default to front-page.php -->
            <li class="list-inline-item modern"><a href="<?php echo site_url()?>" class="text-white lead"><h3 class="menu-items <?php if (is_page('http://modern-artisans--carpentry-version.local/')) echo "modern"?>">home</h3></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="<?php echo site_url('/services')?>" class="text-white lead"><h3 class="menu-items <?php if (is_page('services')) echo "modern"?>">services</h3></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="<?php echo site_url('/about-us')?>" class="text-white lead"><h3 class="menu-items <?php if (is_page('about-us')) echo "modern"?>">about us</h3></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="<?php echo site_url('/index')?>" class="text-white lead"><h3 class="menu-items <?php if (is_page('index')) echo "modern"?>">work history</h3></a></li>
          </ul>
```

Comment: Why not use [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)?

Comment: I could, however, I would like to work with the parameters above. I understand it is not as dynamic as wp_nav_menu but making it work would enhance my skills so to speak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this by using is_front_page() which returns a boolean. You can place that in your if statement in the menu.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/

Comment: Please accept my answer so people know this question is answered.